# Random variable $X$ is given with the density function $ \phi_X (x)= \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$ Find the distribution of the random variable $Y$ if:

Tags: probability, random-variables

$$Y=\begin{cases}-X-2,\ \ \ \  X \leq -1 \\ \ \ \  X, \ \ \ \ \ -1 \leq X \leq 1 \\ \ \ \ \ 1, \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ X >1 \end{cases}$$

Now I'm only interested in $t >1.$ (That is only difficult..)

$$F_Y (t)=P\{ Y<t\}= 1- P\{Y>t \}=1- P\{-X-2 >t\}=1- P\{X <-t-2 \}=1-\int_{- \infty}^{-t-2}\frac{1}{2} e^{-x}dx $$

Comment: Your density function doesn't integrate to $1$

Comment: It's probably supposed to be $\phi_X(x) = \frac12 e^{-|x|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $X$ has the standard Laplace density $.5e^{-|x|}.$
Then $F_Y(t) = 1 - .5e^{-(t+2)},$ for $t > 1.$

Notice that the CDF of $Y$ is not continuous; it has a jump at 1.

*Addendum:* If you have R (free from r.project.org) you can do the following
simulation and plot the empirical CDF of the simulated data (which
very closely imitates the CDF of Y). Then plot my part of the CDF (for
t > 1) through the ECDF. Matches exactly.

```
 m = 10^5;  x = sample(c(-1,1), m, rep=T)*rexp(m) # generate 100000 x's
 y = x;  y[x<= -1]= (-x-2)[x<=-1];  y[x > 1] = 1  # transform
 plot.ecdf(y, main="", ylab="ECDF of Y", xlab="y")
 t = seq(1,10, by=.01)  # plotting points for curve
 lines(t, 1-.5*exp(-t-2), col="green")
```

Comment: Are you saying, my answer is correct

Comment: Does your integral evaluate to give what I have?

Comment: I think it does?

Comment: I\m not sure if thats correct because the density function is in the exponent absolute of x which means it should be -x when x < 0

Comment: Not sure what is correct? The PDF of X is symmetrical. Maybe it is clearer if you integrate that density over a positive interval. Adding a simulation to my answer. I really want you to be clear about this, not just use someone else's answer and move on.

Comment: I very much would like to understand what I am doing wrong in my answer, because I just cannot see what I am getting wrong or not understanding

Comment: I figured it out finally. Thanks for your input.